# space after proof environment name not right in ConTeXt

Tags: context, description

[image]I defined a general environment using `setupenumerations`. Then I defined an `example` and `proof` environments that inherited from it. The proof isn't supposed to be a numbered and setting `number=no` in the options brings an awkward space after the heading like this:

```
\setupenumerations[
  before={\blank[medium]},
  after={\blank[medium]},
  alternative=serried,
  right=.,
  distance=0.5em,
  width=fit,
  headstyle=bold,
  titlestyle=bold,
]

\defineenumeration[example][
  text=Example,
]

\defineenumeration[proof][
  text=Proof,
  number=no,
  right=.,
  distance=1em,
  headstyle=italic,
  title=no,
  closesymbol={\mathematics{\square}},
  style=normal,
]

\starttext

\startexample
  Something here...
\stopexample

\startproof 
  For the first property, we know that at the very least $\emptyset$ and $R$ itself are subsets of $R$ and so it is satisfied. Since $R$ is a ring, $rs \in R$ for $r,s \in R$. Consequently, there exists $S \subseteq R$ which contains $rs$. We know that $\langle R,+\rangle$ is an abelian group and so $s + r \in R$. Also, $s - r = s + (-r)$ where $-r\in R$ is the unique inverse of $r$ under the binary operation $+$. Again, there exists $S \subseteq R$ such that $s-r \in S$.
\stopproof
\stoptext
```

How do I get rid of the extra space marked in the proof environment so it becomes more like that of the Example i.e the space between `proof` and `For the first...` space?

Comment: Can you add picture to show what you mean, when I run your example I don't see anything unusual.

Comment: @WolfgangSchuster thank you for your comment. Please take another look.

Comment: The example environment uses `alternative=serried` but the proof env does not. Add `alternative=serried` in the proof env to get a similar output.

Comment: @Spirit_bird The space after the title in the `proof` environment is larger because you have `distance=1em` in the definition of the environment.

Comment: @Aditya thanks for the comment. I thought It would inherit it from the ```setupenumerations```?

Comment: @WolfgangSchuster thanks it has worked. Also why is the dot in example ie ```right=.,```  not showing in the proof environment head name even though I explicity added it?

Comment: @Spirit_bird The `right` is ignored because you're using a unnumbered title but you can set symbols before and after the title with `headcommand=\groupedcommand{<before>}{<after>}`.

Comment: @WolfgangSchuster it worked. Thanks. Very difficult onboarding experience for me with ConTeXt. I have read most of the manuals but I don't know where to get a specific thing when I need it. Plus they seem to cover only basic functionality. For example, I have ```conTeXt commands``` book but some of the commands are not self explanatory. Any idea a better way to go about learning ConTeXt? I feel embarassed asking such simple questions.

Comment: Not sure if this helps: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/448812/the-definitive-guide-to-context-mkiv-documentation